# How to sort likert heatmap by descending order of last column

Tags: r

Using likert package to plot some likert scales. When plotting bars they are sorted by default. I need to sort the heatmap the same way but no success so far.
As you can see heatmap is ordered by alphabetical text from questions.

Using demo data & code from package:

```
# Reverse the levels
items24.reverse <- reverse.levels(items24)
l24.reverse <- likert(items24.reverse)
plot(l24.reverse)
```

[image]

I want heatmap ordered like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likert package does not allow to do such manipulation. 
Heatmap is ALWAYS ordered by alphabetically sorted text. So I suggest a workaround by forcing the text to be previously sorted by the column you think the most likely to be like bar chart sorting. A bit nasty but works:

```
   library(magrittr)
   library(dplyr)

# Get the results data frame out of the list
# and sort by last column ("Strongly agree")
# padding with zeros to avoid alphabetical ordering

 l24.results <- l24.reverse$results %>%
      dplyr::arrange(desc(`Strongly agree`)) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(Item = paste(str_pad(row_number(),2, pad = "0"), Item, sep = ' '))


# create a likert object again from the summary feature

  mylikert <- likert(summary = l24.results)

# plot again

plot(mylikert, type = "heat")
```

[image]